# Jquery ui draggable uses the top left corner to snap to a grid, is it possible to change that to top right, bottom right etc?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Currently when snapping to a grid I can't move my draggable element to the edge of the page since it's snapping to the top left. I'm guessing this is due to the width of the element not being divisible equally by the grid so it cant move all the way over to the next grid co-ordinate?

Comment: first place i looked!

Comment: No way to do this out of the box. Using the `drag` function, you could replicate the Snap code with your desired coordinates. Please provide a [mcve].